# Git diff considering newly created files with same content as changed

Tags: git, diff

I have an application that reads an input file "input.txt" and generates a new one, in the same folder also named "input.txt" (thus the original file is overwritten). In some situations, this output file has the exact same content as the original one but, of course, it's a new file and I assume some metadata info differs from the original one. These files are in a GIT repository and even if the content remains exactly the same, the git diff is showing that those files have been changed (but of course, without any text difference). Is it possible to say to git to only consider the raw text inside those files when doing their diff an ignore other info e.g. the files metadata?

Comment: Have you compared the files in a hex editor to see what the exact difference is?

Comment: Typically the invisible difference has to do with line endings, but recently we've seen (on StackOverflow) cases where one tool starts a file with a Unicode byte order mark and the other doesn't. Git sees and displays this difference, but since it is a zero-width non-breaking space, the difference is invisible to human eyes.

Comment: Can you show part of an example diff output?  Is the only change the permissions?